# I can't access elements from .edmx file

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, edmx

I am not even sure if the question is correct...

I want to learn basics of asp.net and I found this tutorial "watch?v=BKujvivVFKI" but I am stuck at min 18:00. I don't get that "ProductType. I get

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=303liy1&s=8#.VPkFXEmsK00

I have come to conclusion I can't access files from Model1.edmx because my solution explorer is totally different in App_Code... but this is how it's generated by default when I use that wizard.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=3582kgy&s=8

I have done more than twice same thing what he done... I don't even understand why model1.tt have so many .cs files. In comment section is nothing and from this site I didn't found something related to this.

I have a feeling this is a dumb question, hope I don't get downvoted...
Thanks for patience

Comment: I solved the problem... I created Model1.edmx outside the App_Code and now it's global.... This post can be locked now, thanks everyone.